# mrgalaxy:stripe App is not defined

Tags: meteor, strip

This Meteor web browser site uses the package [mrgalaxy:stripe](https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe), The first instruction is to 
put `App.accessRule('https://*.stripe.com/*');` in a client side file `mobile-config.js`.
Which when done exactly, causes the browser to issue an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined

I looked in [Meteor doc](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html) but could not figure it out.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have that file in the root of your app, not inside your `client` folder.

From [mrgalaxy:stripe documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe):

> In order for Stripe.js to be loaded directly on iOS and Android a new rule needs to be created in your mobile-config.js located in the **root** of your project. Create the new file if it doesn't already exist and insert the line below.

This is necessary for mobile builds to access external URLs. If you're building a mobile app from Meteor, you'll need to add additional configuration info to that `mobile-config.js` file before deploying. See https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html